# How to return 404 when called edit-comments.php?

Tags: comments, wp-admin

I [removed the `edit-comments.php` link from the backend](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/11222/74281) but I can still access to it when I know the link `./wp-admin/edit-comments.php`.

**How can I deactivate this link as well and return a HTTP 404?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can approach this.  I wouldn't recommend deleting edit-comments.php as this is changing the core files, and your changes will be lost when you update WordPress.

### htaccess

```
301 Redirect /wp-admin/edit-comments.php http://www.example.com/wp-admin/
```

### OR functions.php

#### Part 1

```
// Redirect any user trying to access comments page
function custom_disable_comments_admin_menu_redirect() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow === 'edit-comments.php') {
        wp_redirect(admin_url()); exit;
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'custom_disable_comments_admin_menu_redirect');
```

#### Part 2

```
// Remove the menu item for comments from the side
function custom_disable_comments_admin_menu() {
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_disable_comments_admin_menu');
```

#### Part 3

```
// Remove comments links from admin bar
function custom_disable_comments_admin_bar() {
    if (is_admin_bar_showing()) {
        remove_action('admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_comments_menu', 60);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'custom_disable_comments_admin_bar');
```

Comment: "Part 1" is what I was looking for! Thx